# Setting up a Tomcat server that can handle SOAP messages

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, wsdl

I managed to install and get a tomcat server up and running locally. My question is what would I need to do so that I can get the server to handle SOAP messages? I have a server on the other end that sends SOAP messages based on a WSDL. I want the server on my end to process these SOAP messages. Would I have to create a server side application to do this or would Tomcat automatically handle these messages. I can't find any tuts online on how a beginner should approach this.

Comment: The server already handles the messages, is up to you to define a strategy to process/consume them.

Comment: Where can I see these messages? Is there a shell that allows me to see ingoing and outgoing calls?

Comment: Looks like you think of Tomcat as a message processor. That's not its main work. Yes, you will need a server side application that will fire a request to the web service and consume the response for you. There are tools like Apache CXF that helps you do this, or use JAX-WS that already comes with Java SE 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a web application that uses one of the various toolkits for this purpose, such as the builtin JAX-WS, or Apache CXF, or Metro/Glassfish, or ...

Comment: So I'll have to create an application using JAX-WS to see these messages. Would I have to make the application bind to the sending server or will the app process any messages that come in.

Comment: I've never seen a web service package bind to a particular client.